# Getting Value of a tag along with subtags as a String using JAX-B or tell me another std. Parser which can do that

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb

I have an XML which has the following format (a simplified example)

```
<Service id = "1">
<Message>
<options id="standard"> 
                    <option name="autorendered"> 
                        <value> 1</value> 
                    </option> 
                    <option name="environment"> 
                        <value> V</value> 
                    </option> 
                    <option name="document_name"> 
                        <value> Mail - MY Test Mail2.pdf</value> 
                    </option> 
                    <option name="document_provider"> 
                        <value> LNotes</value> 
                    </option> 
</options>
</Message>
</Service>


<Service id = "2">
    <Message>
    <options id="standard"> 
                        <option name="autorendered"> 
                            <value> 4</value> 
                        </option> 
                        <option name="environment"> 
                            <value> V</value> 
                        </option> 
                        <option name="document_name"> 
                            <value> attachment1.jpg</value> 
                        </option> 
                        <option name="document_provider"> 
                            <value> LNotes</value> 
                        </option> 
    </options>
    </Message>
    </Service>
```

Now when I use JAXB and create mapping classes it works fine normally. But I require the value of the Message tag whatever comes in between as a String but if I do that it returns empty value.
But if I have a tag like hello and use `service.getMessage()`, it returns me `hello` properly.

I want service.getMessage to return `<options>.....</option>` as a String.

If not possible in JAX-B kindly suggest me something else like Jaxpath, Xpath, Stax or some other std recognized way of doing it.

My Service class looks like this -

```
public class Service {      
    private Request request;

    @XmlElement(name = "Request")
    public Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(Request edmsRequest) {
        this.request = request;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not very complex. There are multiple service tags, I have to extract the inner xml (of tall the message tags) and send it to some other service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to marshall a string using JAXB that sometimes contains XML content and sometimes does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428727/how-to-marshall-a-string-using-jaxb-that-sometimes-contains-xml-content-and-some)

Answer (score 0):

When JAXB creates the POJO, is it enough that you have a method that creates the string as you need?
 You could create a utility method to do the same.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly what you meant. Can you elaborate upon that please? It would be better if you could write some code. I added a sample Service class I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlAnyElement` annotation can be used to keep portions of an XML document as XML in the resulting object structure.  The `@XmlAnyElement` annotation allows you to set a `DomHandler` which allows you to control how the XML is represented:  DOM, String, etc.

**Examples**

- [How to marshall a string using JAXB that sometimes contains XML content and sometimes does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428727/how-to-marshall-a-string-using-jaxb-that-sometimes-contains-xml-content-and-some/12429211#12429211)
- [Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5553682#5553682)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html