# JAXB - marshal java object with XML string field

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

**suppose i have an object with String property that has an XML string. like:**

```
 class myObject {
    String xml;

    @XmlElement(name = "xml", type = String.class)
    public String getXml() {
        return xml;
    }

    public void setXml(String xml) {
        this.xml = xml;
    }
}
```

i set an XML String to this property - such as

```
 myObject.setXml("<xml>bbb</xml>");
```

now i want to marshal it using JAXB and i get:

```
<xml>&lt;xml&gt;bbb&lt;/xml&gt;</xml>
```

where i want to get

```
<xml>bbb</xml>
```

how can i do it?

EDIT: 
the problem is that String xml, stores a well formatted XML as a string. so I want this string to be marshaled without escaping the XML characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store an XML fragment as a `String` in your Java model, then you can use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation with a `DomHandler` specified to achieve this.

**Examples on Stack Overflow**

- [JAXB use String as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294)
- [How to marshall a string using JAXB that sometimes contains XML content and sometimes does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428727/how-to-marshall-a-string-using-jaxb-that-sometimes-contains-xml-content-and-some/12429211#12429211)
- [Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5553682#5553682)

Comment: never used a DOMHandler. How to do that?

Comment: @kosta - The three Stack Overflow answers I linked to each contain a full example of how to implement a `DomHandler`.