# Complex type to String unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

Can anyone tell me how to convert a complex object into a String in JAXB?

Scenario:
The Car objects below has a nested element called Person. The Person element has 2 fields. Does anyone know how to unmarshall the Person object into a single string? I do not need any other information, just the Person name.

Is there a way to do this with JAXB?

E.g.

XML

```
<Car>
    <Owner>
        <Name>
          John Blogs
        </name>
     </owner>
</Car>
```

How do I create a Java object like the following:

```
class Car{
    private String owner; //John Blogs
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get round the issue in the comment I posted above I used Eclipse MOXy's @XmlPath attribute and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an XML fragment as a `String` in your Java model, then you can use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation with a `DomHandler` specified to achieve this.

**Examples on Stack Overflow**

- [JAXB use String as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294)
- [How to marshall a string using JAXB that sometimes contains XML content and sometimes does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428727/how-to-marshall-a-string-using-jaxb-that-sometimes-contains-xml-content-and-some/12429211#12429211)
- [Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5553682#5553682)

Comment: I have implemented your suggested but I have an issue. My XML object has many Car objects. When I parse the document, the name of the first Person object found is repeated for each of the remaining Person string objects. Is there a way to stop this?