# How to generate a class using JAXB whose element can contain a string or XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy, xjc

I am using JAXB to generate classes from an XML schema. I have an element `status` in my XML which may contain plain text or XML (or both). For example, the following are all valid content:

```
<message>
  <status>OK</status>
</message>

<message>
  <status>
    <error>FAIL</error>
  </status>
</message>

<message>
  <status>
    There was an error<error>FAIL</error>
  </status>
</message>
```

Following this previous question - [How to marshall a string using JAXB that sometimes contains XML content and sometimes does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428727/how-to-marshall-a-string-using-jaxb-that-sometimes-contains-xml-content-and-some) - I was able to manually adjust the class to marshal and unmarshal successfully, by using a `DomHandler`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "status"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
public class Message
{
  @XmlAnyElement(StatusDomHandler.class)    
  protected String status;

  public String getStatus() { return status; }
  public void setStatus(String value) { this.status = value; }
}
```

The problem is, I cannot find a way to get JAXB to generate this class. If I write my schema with

```
<xsd:element name='status' type='xsd:string'/>
```

then the generated class contains

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String status;
```

and I can't add the annotation `StatusDomHandler.class` as it is not supported by `@XmlElement`.

But if I write my schema using `<xs:any>` then the generated class contains an `Element` which can only represent a single XML element.

Is there any way I can force JAXB to create a string element as `@XmlAnyElement`? Or is there some other way I can define my schema to allow the generated element to contain either text or XML element(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify that your type has *mixed* content to get the behaviour you are looking for:

```
<xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:any/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```