# While Sending Xml File into the Soap Reqest Getting Problems in java

Tags: java, xml, string, soap

I am using SoapRequst For my Desktop application. but There is one Soap request in which i hav to Send xml Document but when i tried to add that xml file means Document then that is converted into the String format i means all "<>" clauses converted into the String formate "<" like this.

So what i should do to make them remain into the XMl format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Update xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <doc>xml</doc>
    </Update>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

when i am sending file its converted to this.

```
**&gt;&lt;Folder&gt;&lt;**
```

that has to be this

```
<Folder>
```

Can i have your valuble suggestion for this thanks in advance.

here my method is.
public static SOAPMessage UpdateAllGroupWithSwitchUserConfiguration() {

```
        try {
            File f = new File("/com/package/package/TreeModel.xml");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
            String xml = "";
            while ((xml = br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(xml.trim());
            }

            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            String serverURI = "http://tempuri.org/";

            // SOAP Envelope
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", serverURI);

            SOAPElement sOAPElement = envelope.addChildElement("UpdateAllGroupWithSwitchUserConfiguration", "tem");

            String XML_String = builder.toString();

//            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//            DocumentBuilder doc_builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
//            
//            Document document = doc_builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML_String)));
//            
//            TransformerFactory factory1 = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
//            Transformer transformer = factory1.newTransformer();
//            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
//            Result result = new StreamResult(xml);
//            transformer.transform(source, result);

            SOAPElement xml_APElement = sOAPElement.addChildElement("doc", "tem");
            xml_APElement.addTextNode(builder.toString());




            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "UpdateAllGroupWithSwitchUserConfiguration");

            soapMessage.saveChanges();

            /*
             * Print the request message
             */
            System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");

            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);

            return soapMessage;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

i have put on comment what i have tried.

Comment: Make the data section - as CDATA

Comment: how to do that?? i dont have idea dude..

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136375/how-to-generate-cdata-block-using-jaxb

Comment: i am not getting what it is trying to say dude can u post an example>?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how the structure of you main XML document is defined. Can you post the XSD?
E.g. if in the main XSD you define the doc element to be from another specific XSD with a given namespace eg. "myExternalDocumentNamespace", then you can include it the way you tried, just adding the namespace of the  element, e.g.

```
<Folder xmlns="myExternalDocumentNamespace">
...
</Folder>
```

Depending on your case you may prefer to use an xs:any element in the main XSD, though in the end that also boils down to the same.

Comment: Well its just a Xml document like this let me post it
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Folder>
    <Folder attributes></Folder>
</Folder>

Comment: If you're not working with XSD's I advise you to do so.

Comment: but i dont know while creating this i didnt do that now what to do means how to attach this file in soap request ? u have idea??

Comment: Do you want to attach the content of a file in your xml message or do you want to add one xml structure inside another xml structure?

Comment: i just want to add that all content inside that tag in soap request. :)

Comment: In that case you should start using XSD's. One for the main document and one for the one you're trying to insert inside the other.

Comment: i dont know how to use it can u give me one simple example of that?

Comment: That is the example of XSD and ya if i bind that with SOAP would it going to cause problem??

Comment: No, SOAP has its own namespace. So when you've learned to handle multiple namespaces then SOAP will just be one of them.