# How to add <![CDATA[ and ]]> in XML prepared by Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

How to prepare XML with CDATA ,

I am preraring this response via Jaxb,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <tem:RequestData>
     <tem:requestDocument>
        <![CDATA[
        <Request>
           <Authentication CMId="68" Function="1" Guid="5594FB83-F4D4-431F-B3C5-EA6D7A8BA795" Password="poihg321TR"/>
           <Establishment Id="4297867"/>
        </Request>
        ]]>
      </tem:requestDocument>
   </tem:RequestData>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But from Jaxb i am not getting CDATA , how to put CDATA inside `<tem:requestDocument>` element.

Here is my Java Code :

```
  public static String test1() {
    try {
        initJB();
        String response = null;
        StringBuffer xmlStr = null;
        String strTimeStamp = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.Envelope envelope = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.Header header = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.Body body = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.RequestData requestData = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.RequestDocument requestDocument = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.RequestDocument.Request request = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.RequestDocument.Request.Authentication authentication = null;
        com.cultagent4.travel_republic.gm.RequestDocument.Request.Establishment establishment = null;

        ObjectFactory objFact = new ObjectFactory();
        envelope = objFact.createEnvelope();
        header = objFact.createHeader();
        envelope.setHeader(header);
        body = objFact.createBody();
        requestData = objFact.createRequestData();


        requestDocument = objFact.createRequestDocument();
        request = new RequestDocument.Request();

        authentication = new RequestDocument.Request.Authentication();
        authentication.setCMId("68");
        authentication.setGuid("5594FB83-F4D4-431F-B3C5-EA6D7A8BA795");
        authentication.setPassword("poihg321TR");
        authentication.setFunction("1");
        request.setAuthentication(authentication);
        establishment = new RequestDocument.Request.Establishment();
        establishment.setId("4297867");
        request.setEstablishment(establishment);
        requestDocument.setRequest(request);
        requestData.setRequestDocument(requestDocument);
        body.setRequestData(requestData);
        envelope.setBody(body);



        jaxbMarshallerForBase = jaxbContextForBase.createMarshaller();
        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        System.out.println();
        // output pretty printed

//                jaxbMarshallerForBase.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
//                jaxbMarshallerForBase.marshal(envelope, System.out);
//                jaxbMarshallerForBase.marshal(envelope, os);


        jaxbMarshallerForBase.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        jaxbMarshallerForBase.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
//            jaxbMarshallerForBase.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
// get an Apache XMLSerializer configured to generate CDATA
        XMLSerializer serializer = getXMLSerializer();


// marshal using the Apache XMLSerializer
        SAXResult result = new SAXResult(serializer.asContentHandler());

         System.out.println("*************");
        jaxbMarshallerForBase.marshal(envelope, result);
        System.out.println("--------------");



        return null;
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GM_TravelRepublic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        return null;
    }
}

private static XMLSerializer getXMLSerializer() {
    // configure an OutputFormat to handle CDATA
    OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat();

    // specify which of your elements you want to be handled as CDATA.
    // The use of the ; '^' between the namespaceURI and the localname
    // seems to be an implementation detail of the xerces code.
    // When processing xml that doesn't use namespaces, simply omit the
    // namespace prefix as shown in the third CDataElement below.
    of.setCDataElements(new String[]{"^Request","^Authentication","^Establishment"});


    // set any other options you'd like
   of.setPreserveSpace(true);
    of.setIndenting(true);


    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    // create the serializer
    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(of);


    serializer.setOutputByteStream(System.out);


    return serializer;
}
```

Here I am getting same xml , but without  CDATA. My server is not accepting the request without CDATA.Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Can you make the logic from this

imports

```
import org.dom4j.CDATA;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
```

sample code

```
public static String appendCdata(String input) {
    CDATA cdata = DocumentHelper.createCDATA(input);      
    return cdata.asXML();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. You need to create an custom adapter class which extends the `XMLAdapter` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CDATAAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String inStr) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + inStr + "]]>";
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return inStr;
    }
}
```

2. Inside your Java Bean or POJO define `XMLJavaTypeAdapter` on the string required in CDATA

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAAdapter.class)
private String message;
```

3. By default, the marshaller implementation of the JAXB RI tries to escape characters. To change this behaviour we write a class that
   implements the `CharacterEscapeHandler`.

This interface has an escape method that needs to be overridden.

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;

m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.characterEscapeHandler",
                new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length,
                            boolean isAttVal, Writer writer)
                            throws IOException {
                        writer.write(ch, start, length);
                    }
                });
```

Secondly, it cn also be done via Eclipse MOXy implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`CDATA` is character data, it looks like your server wants the part of the XML starting with `Request` to come in as text.  It may be enough for you to create an `XmlAdapter` to convert the instance of `Request` to a `String`.  The resulting characters will be escaped not in CDATA but this May fit your use case.

Then if you really need it as CDATA in addition to the `XmlAdapter` you can apply one of the strategies described in the link below:

- [How to generate CDATA block using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136375/how-to-generate-cdata-block-using-jaxb)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your `private static XMLSerializer getXMLSerializer()` method you are setting wrong the `CDATA` elements, because your `CDATA` element is `<tem:requestDocument>` instead of `Request` `Authentication` and `Establishment` which are the content. Try with:

```
of.setCDataElements(new String[]{"tem^requestDocument","http://tempuri.org/^requestDocument","requestDocument"});
```

instead of:

```
of.setCDataElements(new String[]{"^Request","^Authentication","^Establishment"});
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ops sorry @LMK. I'm sure that this is the way, may be I was wrong specifying the matching names (I don't remember the exact syntax), try with:     `of.setCDataElements(new String[]{"ns3^requestDocument","^requestDocument","ns3:requestDocument"});`, I also update the answer. I hope that this time it's more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the [setCDataElements method description](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat.html#setCDataElements(java.lang.String[])) in the Apache docs :

`Sets the list of elements for which text node children should be output as CDATA.`

What I think that means is, the children of the `tem:requestDocument` element should all be part of one single text chunk (and not xml elements by themselves) in order for this to work. Once you've done that, probably a simple

```
of.setCDataElements(new String[]{"tem^requestDocument"});
```

should do the trick.

Try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is expecting `<tem:requestDocument>` to contain *text*, and not
a `<Request>` element. `CDATA` is really just helpful for creating hand-written
XML so you don't have to worry about escaping embedded XML. The thing is,
**JAXB** handles escaping just fine and if your server is a good XML citizen it should
treat properly escaped XML the same as XML in a `CDATA` block.

So, instead of adding a *request* element inside your *requestDocument* like
you do in:

```
requestDocument = objFact.createRequestDocument();
request = new RequestDocument.Request();

...
requestDocument.setRequest(request);
```

You should first use JAXB to marshal *request* into a properly escaped String
and set *that* sa the *requestDocument* value:

```
requestDocument = objFact.createRequestDocument();
request = new RequestDocument.Request();

...
String escapedRequest = marshal(request);
requestDocument.setRequest(escapedRequest);
```

Implementing `marshal(request)` is left as an exercise. ;)