# JAXB and CData without control over generated sources

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, cdata

I have a project using a 3rd party lib, including generated JAXB Java objects (Which I haven no source control over)

I found that one of the elements in this model, expects a `<![CDATA` blob. Is there any way to make Jaxb marshaller aware of this, and not escape the output in that particular field?

The XML model is as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "MyComplexType",
    propOrder = {"val1", "cdataval"}
)
public class MyComplexType {
    @XmlElement(
        name = "val1",
        required = true
    )
    protected String val1;

    protected String cdataval;

    public MyComplexType() {
    }

    ... getter and setters...
}
```

So, as I mentioned earlier, adding CData to the `cdataval` makes JaxB marshaller escape the content leading to invalid CData content.

How could I make the marshaller NOT escape the content, without modifying the generated sources? It would be so easy to just add a special `XmlAdapter` on that field, but nope, can't do that.

Regards

Comment: `CData` is just a way of writing text inside a XML node. It should not be a problem, if that text is written in another form...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto The problem is that it's supposed to contain XML inside that node, so after running `marshaller.marshal(rootObj, writer)` that element get's completely escaped with `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

Comment: That is not a problem. The other party should be able to read and parse it...

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25832468/4899193