# Stop converting < to &lt, > to &gt and & to &amp; in spring controller response

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb2

I am trying to generate a small xml. This xml should have a CDATA in it. Now the problem is I managed to generate CDATA, but the xml that is generated have < and > and &

I am using spring-mvc. I am interested in getting the right xml with CDATA in it.

Sample xml is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customer>
    <Active>1</Active>
    <AlertMessage></AlertMessage>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <CustomerNumber>123</CustomerNumber>
    <Forename>AD</Forename>
    <balancetoallow>
        <balance saving="10" spend="9990" type="2">
            <value>\&lt;![CDATA[$100 off on two  purchase of jeans XYZ Brand.]]\&gt;</value>
        </balance>
    </balancetoallow>
    <Surname>CD</Surname>
</Customer>
```

I have also overridden one of the converter as follow.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

P.S I am using spring rest controller for my web service.

Here is the model class :

```
public class Balance{
    private String value;
    private String type;
    private String saving;
    private String spend;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdapterCDATA.class)
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getSaving() {
        return saving;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setSaving(String saving) {
        this.saving = saving;
    }
    public String getSpend() {
        return spend;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setSpend(String spend) {
        this.spend = spend;
    }
}
```

This class is again part of another class.

```
public class Balancetoallows {  
    private List<Balance> balancetoallow ;

    public List<Balance> getBalancetoallow () {
        return balancetoallow;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="balancetoallow ")
    public void setBalancetoallow (List<Balance > balancetoallow ) {
        this.balancetoallow= balancetoallow;
    }
}
```

And this is part of this class.
The parent class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {

    private String surname ;
    private String forename;
    private BalanceToAllow balanceToAllow;
    private final String active="1";
    private final String currency = "GBP";
    private final String alertMessage="";


    public String getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="CustomerNumber")
    public void setCustomerNumber(String customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Active")
    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="Currency")
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="Surname")
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="Forename")
    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="AlertMessage")
    public String getAlertMessage() {
        return alertMessage;
    }
    public BalanceToAllow getBalanceToAllow() {
        return BalanceToAllow;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="balanceToAllow")
    public void setFuturePromotions(BalanceToAllow balanceToAllow) {
        this.balanceToAllow= balanceToAllow;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136375/how-to-generate-cdata-block-using-jaxb), you should be using the `@XmlCDATA` annotation on the relevant property.

Comment: I have tried using XmlCDATA it doesn't work, I used @XmlJavaTypeAdapter with my custom class AdapterCDATA.java.

Comment: You shouldn't omit such important details. What was wrong with the results of `@XmlCDATA`? Also, please show your model code as well as your type adapter implementation.

Comment: question is updated.

Comment: The result of @XmlCDATA was normal output

Comment: You are missing "@XmlElement" for the value feild. Add this "@XmlElement" annotation on top of "@XmlJavaTypeAdapter".

Comment: With "@XmlElement" on "@XmlJavaTypeAdapter" i am getting the same result again the < is converted into "&lt" and "&gt"