# ADD <![CDATA[ tag inside xml using java Object

Tags: java, xml

i am trying to add <![CDATA[ tag inside xml.
how i can do that.

Result will be like this :-

```
<CERequest>
<inflow format="1">
<![CDATA[ 
<DOC id="2229901"></DOC>
]]>
</inflow>
</CERequest>
```

My java Object :-

**CERequest.java **

```
public class CERequest {
private Inflow inflow;
}
```

**Inflow.java**

```
public class Inflow {   
@XmlAttribute
private String format;
}
```

**Converting java object to xml
**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CERequest .class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(cEOutputRequest, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

after converting how to get cdata

Comment: You can use XSLT for that.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136375/how-to-generate-cdata-block-using-jaxb. The second answer there seems to be what you are looking for.